# What is the return value of XmlElement.RemoveChild() for?

Tags: .net, xml

today I stumbled over something very odd (at least in my opinion) in the .NET xml code. Maybe you can shed some light over this?

Let's say I have a `XmlElement` called *Node_A* with a few child nodes, one of them called *Node_B*.
If I want to remove *Node_B* from *Node_A* I have to call the `RemoveChild` method on *Node_A* and give *Node_B* as a parameter. And this `RemoveChild` method gives me back a `XmlNode` object as a return value, but what for? I already need references to both nodes involved in the deleting to execute the deletion, so there really is no need to give back either *Node_A* or *Node_B*?

Answer (score 1):

This is good when you want to nest calls within other calls. For example through this return value you can remove node from tree and add them to another in one statement.

```
Tree2.AppendChild(Tree1.RemoveChild(x));
```

You may have noted that the opposite function `AppendChild()` also returns the node we just added. This will allow me to write code like:

```
Tree1.AppendChild(child).AppendChild(grandChild);
```

Comment: What about parent1.RemoveChild(child); parent2.AddChild(child);, it's a one-liner too? But ok, you got a point, although not very logical in my opinion. An information about the success or failure of the deletion would be much more helpful...

Comment: One-liners generally refer to single statements, not multiple statements written in one line.